# Can I run power to an induction cook top off of a sub-panel?

Tags: electrical, cooktops

I’m trying to swap from gas cook top to induction cook top.

There’s a sub-panel directly below the cook top and the main panel is prohibitively far away to run power from.

My question is whether or not it can be done or should I scrap this idea?   I called an electrician who said main panel or nothing, will not run it off sub-panel any under circumstances without looking at it.

Here’s what the cook top calls for
[image]

And here’s the panel. The biggest draw would be my well water pump rated at 240/30.

[image]

[image]

Edit based on questions:

Excellent info on the load calculation, I will have that done.  My main panel(s) show a 200a breaker on each and the Sub panel is fed off the right panel and shows two 90a (edited my mistake) I also attached a better picture of the sub panel cover

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You only show one panel. That's presumably the sub-panel, given no main breaker evident - so, what is the feed to this sub-panel? And are there actually spaces under the unused knock-outs? And what is the panel's rated amperage (I can't read the label in that picture, even zoomed in) I can, however, see that your well pump is 240V 20A, not 30A.

Comment: I would ask the electrician if there's a local code that prohibits running stoves/ovens/cook tops from a subpanel. If not, then I'd find a new electrician. Doesn't matter where the power comes from so long as the load calculation works out OK.

Comment: Curious, why are you switching from gas and what do you mean by "prohibitively far"?   Is it cost?  Or is the basement finished so you just can't run a cable like this without tearing up the ceiling in multiple rooms?

Comment: @jay613 the panel is in finished basement and it would require a good 35 foot rip in my ceiling to run the wire spanning a few rooms

Answer (score 7):

You need to do a **Load Calculation**. Actually, two of them - one for the utility service/main panel and another for the subpanel. You are adding 50A to your load. That's 1/4 of a typical 200A service, so it is significant. It is even possible to have smaller service if your cooktop, water heater and heating are all gas.

**Update:** OP uploaded pictures of **two** 200A main panels, and both have plenty of space in them. That hints at a possible 400A/Class 320 service. If that's the case then total load will almost certainly be fine for the new cooktop and at first glance the subpanel feed of 90A is likely to be fine as well. But actual load calculations are needed. Except technically **three** load calculations:

- Total service
- 200A panel that feeds the subpanel
- 90A subpanel

But assuming this is a normal 400A -> 2 x 200A, the total service really shouldn't be an issue.

Your gas cooktop may had a dedicated 20A 120V circuit, but the actual usage would have been < 1A and only for a few seconds at a time, as opposed to 40A 240V for a long time and peaking at 48A 240V.

There are online calculators available. Note that a proper load calculation is *not* "add up all the breakers" and is *not* "stick a clamp meter on the main feeder and see what it shows" (though that can be useful in certain circumstances).

Basically a Load Calculation takes into account:

- Size of your house
- Required dedicated circuits (kitchen, bathroom, laundry)
- HVAC (largest of H or C)
- Large fixed appliances - e.g., water heater, pumps
- Cooking appliances - these get some special rules, but replacing a gas cooktop with an induction cooktop will definitely increase the load

and a bunch of other things.

If your subpanel has room then it is just a question of breaker spaces (which you have), the right size of wires, etc. So do the Load Calculations - to make sure you have enough capacity in your service *and* enough capacity in your subpanel (subpanel total capacity is determined by the breaker feeding it in the main panel) and if there is enough to add 50A, great. If there is not enough then we can discuss possible solutions.

Comment: Need to verify actual spaces on the bus below the blank covers before spaces is a given...

Comment: @Ecnerwal (a) that is far, far more common on much smaller panels - e.g., a 12 space front with an 8 space bus inside; (b) I don't know if CH ever played that game - as a higher end panel maybe they didn't (but I don't know that, just a hunch), (c) even if there are no actual spaces available, any normal CH panel (which appears to be the case here) can have 15A and 20A tandems so worst case 4 15A or 20A circuits can be replaced with tandems, freeing up 2 full spaces.

Comment: I wonder if your electrician really meant "under any circumstances" or if he meant under YOUR circumstances?   If I saw your first picture and was told it's that subpanel or nothing, I don't think I'd come out to do an estimate.  You SHOULD do the load calc, and full confession I have not.  But it looks hopeless to me.

Comment: @jay613 he saw main panel and refused to even look at sub-panel saying it wasn’t safe to run it off sub-panel.  Based on favorable load calculation I’m going to call up someone else for a 2nd opinion

Comment: That's crazy! A 90A subpanel may or may not have enough excess capacity to add a 50A load, and you don't know until you look at it. If it was 60A (or less) then I would agree with the electrician. But 90A is such a common size that someone might run that even if they are just putting in a few 15A or 20A circuits in order to have room for...future expansion...such as a 50A cooktop.

Comment: @jay613 There are a *ton* of variables here. For example, cooking appliances that are used together (not sure exactly...it is in the load calc rules) get a special combination rule which lowers the total amount so it is less than "add up the nameplates".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact actually I made a mistake that produced 68A, it should be lower even as a guesstimate.  I deleted the comment. I think your optimism in warranted.

Comment: @RRsteele -- how many square feet does the panel provide lighting & receptacle circuits two, what do the the circuits marked "dedicated circuit" feed, and how many HP is the well pump?